# Modification to Maximum Flow Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, max-flow, network-flow

I've tried to solve a question about the [maximum-flow problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem). I have one source and two sinks. I need to find a maximum flow in this network. This part is general max-flow. However, both targets have to get same amount of flow in this special version of the max-flow problem.

Is there anyone who can help me what should I do to do that?

Comment: What is the reason of -1  ?

Comment: Are you talking fluid analysis or computer network messages?

Comment: I would start with something along the lines of the same way you'd do general max flow, except at each step, find two augmenting paths, one from the source to each target. Then add enough flow to both paths such that both targets still get the same amount of flow (this is complicated a bit by non-edge disjoint graphs). I'm not sure that doing this will actually result in the max possible for both targets.

Comment: How is the question "unclear"? It's very obvious what is asked, IMHO. Actually in interesting problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let `s` be your source vertex and `t1` and `t2` the two sinks.

You can use the following algorithm:

1. Use regular max-flow with two sinks, for example by connecting `t1` and `t2` to a super-sink via edges with infinite capacities. You now have the solution with maximum `excess(t1) + excess(t2)`, but it might be imbalanced.
2. If `excess(t1) == excess(t2)`, you are done. Otherwise, w.l.o.g. let `excess(t1) > excess(t2)`
3. Run another round of max-flow with source `t1` and sink `t2` in the residual network of step 1. Restrict the flow outgoing from `t1` to `c = floor((excess(t1) - excess(t2)) / 2)`, for example by introducing a super-source `S` connected to `t1` via an edge with the given capacity `c`. Now, `excess(t2)` is the maximum flow you can send to both sinks.
4. If you need to reconstruct the flow values for each edge, do another round of max-flow to transport the `excess(t1) - excess(t2)` leftover units of flow back to the source.

The complexity is that of your max-flow algorithm.

If you already know how to solve max-flow with lower-bound capacities, you can also binary search the solution, resulting in complexity `O(log W * f)` where `W` is the solution value and `f` is the max-flow complexity.

Comment: I'm sorry its not clear how adding a super source to t1 will transfer the flow units to t2. As far as I understand t1 will still remain a sink and transfer of flow 'from' t1 to any other node will be impossible. Sorry again if I mis-understand.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal treat t1 as a normal node and t2 as sink and proceed to do max-flow from new source to t2

Comment: to author: can you explain more explicitly about step 4?

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev t1 has all its edges as incoming edges (since it is a sink). How can it be considered a normal node?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal i think it is assumed that graph is bidirectional, in your case, i guess, you need to reverse directions of all edges to t1 except the one from new source, try like that, i'm not sure

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: "t1 has all its edges as incoming edges (since it is a sink). How can it be considered a normal node". Doesn't matter. You just add an additional incoming edge that has capacity `floor((excess(t1) - excess(t2)) / 2)` and add it to a newly introduced source `S`. You can also think about it as setting `supply(t1) = floor((excess(t1) - excess(t2)) / 2)` and `demand(t2) = ∞`. The super-source is just a way to solve that.

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev: Let's say in the initial max-flow, `t1` receives 6 units of flow and `t1` receives 2. We now try to transfer 2 unit of flow from `t1` to `t2` for balancing. Now it might happen that this doesn't work, we just achieve to send 1 unit of flow from `t1` to `t2`, so we end up with `excess(t1) = 5` and `excess(t2) = 3`. The solution here is that both nodes receive 3 units of flow (the minimum of the two), so we need to send 2 units of flow from `t1` back to the original source in the residual network (another max-flow problem).

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev: And no, the graph is not assumed to be bidirectional. The algorithm would still work though.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: Sorry, I think I now understand better where you had a problem understanding the algorithm: "As far as I understand t1 will still remain a sink and transfer of flow 'from' t1 to any other node will be impossible." We are working on the residual network after step 1, so if `excess(t1) != 0`, then it will in fact have some outgoing residual edges!

Comment: @NiklasB. so to balance to 3 (in this example), we should apply max-flow where source is t1 and sink is s?

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev: Yep. In the residual network after step 3, that is. Of course we only need to do this if we want the complete flow function, since we already know the value of the solution is 3.

Comment: @NiklasB. I tried your algorithm using Edmonds-Karp. It updates flows correctly in the first step, but then it fails to update properly when I do it for supersource and sink t2 as well as when applying it in step 4. I think I implemented the Edmonds-Karp algorithm correctly, what can be my mistake in your opinion?

Comment: @Kudayar: Do you always use the residual network from the last step?

Comment: @NiklasB. Yes, only Edmonds-Karp itself changes flow matrix

Comment: @Kudayar: What do you mean by "fails to update properly"? I mean it should always respect the flow balance and flow conservation constraints. If it does and there exists a residual path from `t1` to `t2` in step 3, it should find it. It should never enter an inconsistent state.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46119/discussion-between-niklas-b-and-kudayar-pirimbaev)

Comment: @NiklasB. fixed it, was improperly using breadth-first, thanks for help

Comment: @NiklasB. Thank you, I understand now. I had forgotten that we are working on the residual graph, not the original one.