# How to compute Maximum Flow in a tree with (One source - Many sinks), what are the existing approaches to do that?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

Actually there are discussions about this problem:

- [Modification to Maximum Flow Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268613/modification-to-maximum-flow-algorithm)
- [How to find the maximum flow in a multi source flow network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51009304/how-to-find-the-maximum-flow-in-a-multi-source-flow-network)

The approach is to add another node (source/sink or both) and add also edges (with infinite capacities) to link them with the rest of nodes. Finally, we got a graph with one source - one sink, afterward, we just apply the Maximum Flow Algorithm.

**My Questions:**

1. How to compute Maximum Flow for graph contains **infinite capacities** since all `NetworkX` methods does not support it?
2. Are there any other methods to solve this kind of problem?

Thank you

Comment: If you have float capacities, why not use `math.inf`? Otherwise, I would go with `sys.maxsize`.

Comment: @ypnos thank you, unfortunately the maximum flow method included in NetworkX library does not support **infinite capacity**. Is there a way to adapt this method or are there any other methods ?

Comment: I use graph-tool instead of networkx, it takes long to compile but worth it. See https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/flow.html for maximum flow algorithms.

Comment: Very useful, thanks

Comment: Two nodes with an infinite-capacity edge between them can just be merged.